# Kotlin - How to remove Letter from Word with Overloading Minus and for Loops?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, operator-overloading

Hallo Coding Friends,

i working since a week on a Kotlin Challange.
The Challange is to remove a letter from a Word but it must be with "Operator Overloading" and "for" Loop.
I already done it with filter method and it works but is doesnt finish the Challange.

My Programm - Theoretical i know it can be done but practice is another World

```
operator fun String.minus(filter1: String): String {
    return filter1.minus("l")
}

fun main() {
    val wortHW1 = "Hallo"
    val wortHW2 = "Hallo World"
    for (x in wortHW1) {
        x.minus('l')
    }
}
```

I really hope you all can help me, stuck since a weeks.

***Thx for all your effort***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buildString` function is a useful way to write concise String manipulation code. For example:

```
operator fun String.minus(removedChar: Char): String = buildString {
    for (c in this@minus) {
        if (c != removedChar) append(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx you so much and how code it would looks if you have to use + Operator to create new String?

Comment: The + operator already does this. `“Hallo” + “!”` returns a new String `”Hallo!”`.

Comment: thx you. Your Code is even shorter xD

Comment: Even shorter would be `filter { it != removedChar }` if you aren’t being forced to use a for loop.

Comment: Yes, i know but this Challange must be done in specific way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and given the requiremets this is what you are looking for:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val wortHW1 = "Hallo"
    val wortHW2 = "Hallo World"
    println(wortHW1.minus('l'))
    println(wortHW2.minus(' '))
}

operator fun String.minus(letterToRemove: Char): String {
    val lettersToKeep: MutableList<Char> = mutableListOf()
    for (letter in this) {
        if (letter != letterToRemove) {
            lettersToKeep.add(letter)
        }
    }

    return lettersToKeep.joinToString("")
}
```

Comment: Then you just need to replace `'l'` with `' '`as follows: `println(wortHW2.minus(' '))`. If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and accepting it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thx you so much. i never though if the mutable list.

Comment: No need to thank me, that is why the community exists. Nevertheless, accept the answer as the correct one so that your question can be "closed" and others may benefit from it. Thanks ;)

Comment: And what if i must use + Operator to put letter to a new String?

Comment: The + operator already does that for Strings, and you can’t shadow it because it is not an extension function.